# Fused data improve the model performance compared to models from single dataset?

Tags: lme4-nlme, model

I have two types of 3d scan datasets over 200 forest plots. One type of data have higher resolution (more detailed information on the landscape) than the other. I derived 10 forest metrics from these dataset such as height, volume, crown cover and etc. I also have field data of animal abundance and species richness in those plots. I would like to see the relationship between the animal abundance and species richness and 3d metrics of forest plots using the mixed effects model (glmer). Models from single datasets found that some metrics are significant for animal abundance. I also fused the data from two types of sensors hoping it can improve the models. But what I found is pretty surprising. Some variables that are important from single dataset models are not important in fused models. I would appreciate any thoughts and ideas why this is happening.